# Where to to put packages of nltk_data in subfolders

Tags: python, download, package, nltk

Hello I'm running under proxy server on my company, I've problem of nltk.download() as proxy block it.

I've attempted method of passing proxy by using

> nltk.set_proxy('http://xxxxxx:*****@www.abc.xy:8080')

This to do not work. I've created subfolders of nltk_data to store package that I'll get from 
[nltk data](https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/) but my problem is I do not know where to put downloaded packages in these subfolders.

NB: Subfolders are: chunkers, grammars, misc, sentiment, taggers, corpora, help, models, stemmers, tokenizers;
So if I download porter stemmer or Punkt Tokenizer Models where to unzip them.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the github repo for nltk.  The link shows the directory structure for nltk_data.  Hope this helps

https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/tree/gh-pages/packages

Comment: Thanks I've downloaded this automatically hope it works.